# JavaFX8 - FXML How to call method with parameters in onAction-tag?

Tags: java, textfield, javafx-8, fxml

How is it possible to call a method with parameters out of FXML?

In Java I use this code:

```
textfield.setOnAction(event -> {
    endEdit(false);
});
```

In FXML I know I can call a method like this:

```
<TextField onAction="#endEdit">
```

So how can I call the method `endEdit(Boolean)` in FXML with the parameter `false`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just encapsulate the `endEdit(...)` method call in a `@FXML` annotated method that handles the action event. Something like this:

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    protected void handleTextFieldAction(ActionEvent e) {
        endEdit(false);
    }

    private void endEdit(boolean flag) {
        System.out.println("Flag value: " + flag);
        // Your implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }  
}
```

Then in your `FXML` file bind the text field's onAction property to this `handleTextFieldAction(...)` method like this:

```
<TextField onAction="#handleTextFieldAction" />
```

If the boolean flag actually depends on some conditions that have to be evaluated then you can process them within `handleTextFieldAction(...)` method and call `endEdit(...)` with the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought there could be a way to call the method directly out of the FXML, so there would be less code necessary.

Comment: You're welcome. It would be nice but: *"In general, a handler method should conform to the signature of a standard event handler; that is, it should take a single argument of a type that extends javafx.event.Event and should return void (similar to an event delegate in C#). The event argument often carries important and useful information about the nature of the event; however, it is optional and may be omitted if desired."* Extracted [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) (applies to JavaFX8 too) @S.Pro